# How to append or merge data frome first dataframe from first row to another from 11row

Tags: python, dataframe

I tried use this code:

```
Antonio_trade_merge = antonio_trade [["NAZIV ARTIKLA","EAN CODE",]].append(Dobavljaci[["NAZIV ARTIKLA","EAN CODE"]])
```

but i got this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['NAZIV ARTIKLA', 'EAN CODE'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: better create minimal working code with example data in code - this way we can see test it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the df have those columns
2. your code has space in it after antonio_trade" "[["NAZIV ARTIKLA","EAN CODE",]] remove that space and give it a try

   Antonio_trade_merge = antonio_trade"**space_to_be_removed**"[["NAZIV ARTIKLA","EAN CODE",]].append(Dobavljaci[["NAZIV ARTIKLA","EAN CODE"]])
3. Also there's a difference between merge and append, merge joins 2 tables, append adds all the rows to the other table, so what do you want to do?

Can you show an example output that would be helpful

Comment: 1. on first df which i want to import into i have those columns, also on Template i have those name of columns, but from 11 row, becouse on the first 10 was text and watermark.  and because of that i think. Append fit more.